# sourcing Python function from R not importing modules

Tags: python, r, reticulate

The reticulate documentation says that I can source any Python script just as I would source an R script using the source_python() function. I tried the example they provided but it does not work for me. I am getting " No module named pandas" error.

first i specify the path to my python

```
library(reticulate)
use_python("/Users/fberhane/anaconda3/bin/python", required=TRUE)
```

then save the python code below as flights.py

```
import pandas
def read_flights(file):
    flights = pandas.read_csv(file)
    flights = flights[flights['dest'] == "ORD"]
    flights = flights[['carrier', 'dep_delay', 'arr_delay']]
    flights = flights.dropna()
    return flights
```

Then I source the above python code after first saving it as flights.py

```
source_python("flights.py")
flights <- read_flights("flights.csv")

library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(flights, aes(carrier, arr_delay)) + geom_point() + geom_jitter()
```

but I get the error message that there is no module called pandas.

Comment: check if `reticulate::py_config()` returns the path to the python executable that you have specified in `use_python()`. You might want to restart the R session if not and try again.

Comment: Even if I restart it after I have used use_python,  py_config still gives /usr/bin/python

Comment: the same code if I put it in R Notebooks and knit it, it works fine.

Comment: but when I create an Rscript with the same code and source it, it says 'No module named pandas'. I think it is using /usr/bin/python in this case

Comment: The same code when I create a shiny app with it, it works fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, sorry.

Comment: I am using Mac. Can that have some additional settings to configure?

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue, I am using a Mac too.